# NSURL with http:// works fine but with ftp:// not

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ftp, nsurl

```
NSString *adress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ftp://%@:%@@%@/%@x050-pegel.txt", benutzer.text, passwort.text, server.text, pfad.text];

NSURL *aURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:adress];

NSString *theData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:aURL];

textview.text = theData;
```

can some one help me please ?

Comment: Thanks for your request, i find ConnectionKit and im going to try this.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, FTP support is not part of the Cocoa frameworks.  You could get more information by using [`+[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJBFBJC) and looking at the `NSError` object, like so:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *theData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:aURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error != nil) {
  NSLog(@"received error: %@", error);
}
```

A quick google search for "cocoa ftp" shows that there are several approaches to connecting to an FTP server from Objective-C.