# Writing file to secure server

Tags: iphone, file-upload

I'm trying to write a text file to a secure server .....

```
-(IBAction) startUpload{
    NSLog(@"Start upload");

    NSString *myString = @"TESTTEXT";
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@72.167.1.1/testfile.plist"];

    NSError *error;

    BOOL ok = [myString writeToURL:myURL atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (!ok) { // if NOT ok
        NSLog(@"error writing to file at %@, %@, %@",myURL,[error localizedFailureReason],[error localizedDescription]);
    }

}
```

... and all I get is this error message ....

error writing to file at ftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@72.167.1.1/testfile.plist, (null), The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 518.)

All help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think FTP is not supported as NSURL,

take a look to this question: [NSURL with http:// works fine but with ftp:// not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109091/nsurl-with-http-works-fine-but-with-ftp-not)

also take a look to this one

[Upload photo to arbitrary FTP with iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128378/upload-photo-to-arbitrary-ftp-with-iphone-app)

Comment: Thanks Diego.  Reading the other posts, it looks like everyone is struggling with these libraries.  There doesn't seem to be any 101 tutorials that actually show working up-and downloads to FTP site.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [s7ftprequest](http://code.google.com/p/s7ftprequest/)

#### Description:

> This project was inspired by a marvelous lib that I'm using in all my apps that involve network interactions (I can hardly remember one without any): ASIHTTPRequest.
>
> This is the product of composing together ASIHTTPRequest design solutions and SimpleFTPSample techniques.

Comment: Hi I have tried that library too, it doesn't work. No errors, but equally no upload.  I see others have had same issue.  Would you mind trying it and posting code for all to see.  Many thanks.